# Nodes failing to start correctly Google Kubernetes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am fairly new to Google Cloud Platform(GCP) and also Kubernetes.

I was trying to run Cassandra using Kubernetes Engine and GCP provides one-click support to create everything. Because I was just testing, I decided to stop all the VM to prevent unwanted billing after I successfully created the Cassandra.

Then when I tried to run it again, it doesn't work because somehow the nodes aren't created. I decided to delete everything from the Cassandra application and also the clusters. Now I tried to do the same thing and it always fails to create the nodes. I haven't even got to the Cassandra part because I need to create the clusters and the nodes first.

[Click here to see the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkruD.png)

No further error details, that's all I've got.

The clusters (Compute Engine/VM) are working fine and I've tried this three times with different regions and different names. But nothing works and the nodes keep failing. It doesn't mention why it fails. I couldn't create a running cluster because the error says that the nodes failed to start. I don't have any experience in Kubernetes and clusters.

Also, I couldn't contact support because you have to pay monthly for that and I am just doing my course project for my university course. Does anyone know what happened and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to your cluster not being deleted correctly. I would manually create a cluster using this command [1], You will then be able to select it from the click to deploy menu.

[1] gcloud beta container clusters create CLUSTER_NAME \
--addons=HorizontalPodAutoscaling,HttpLoadBalancing,Istio,CloudRun \
--machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
--cluster-version=latest --zone=ZONE \
--enable-stackdriver-kubernetes \
--scopes cloud-platform

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I've tried that and the result is still the same:

 "finished with error: All cluster resources were brought up, but the cluster API is reporting that: only 0 nodes out of 3 have registered; this is likely due to Nodes failing to start correctly; try re-creating the cluster or contact support if that doesn't work."

I am guessing there is something wrong with my GCP account.